# How do I find deprecated code in my php when page won't load?

Tags: php, mysql

I upgraded to php 8.2 from 7.4 (tried 8.0 after as well but same issue)
I get a 500 error and my host won't allow me to revert back to 7.4 now so I need to figure this out but I have no idea how I am supposed to investigate this if I can't get info from console on what is wrong

1. Can anyone tell me what is wrong here?
2. How do you go about troubleshooting your code for upgrades like this?

```
<?php
error_reporting(?int $error_level = null): int
include '../functions.php';

$cardsquery = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM pf_cards");
$cardsquery->bind_param("ss", $season, $set);


$cardsquery->execute();
$cardsresult = $cardsquery->get_result();

$card_data = [];

while ($pfcards = $cardsresult->fetch_assoc()) {
    // Extract and format data as needed
    $card = [
        'card_image' => $pfcards['card_image'],
        'season' => $pfcards['season'],
        'card_set' => $pfcards['card_set'],        
        'pocketfur_cn' => $pfcards['pocketfur_cn'],     
        'set_number' => $pfcards['set_number'],
        'rarity' => $pfcards['rarity'],
        'card_cn' => $pfcards['card_cn'],
    ];
    $card_data[] = $card;
}

// Output the data as JSON
header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($card_data);
?>
```

I tried searching different parts of the code on php official site but there is nowhere on the pages that says if its only supported in 8.2 or if its changed. And the upgrade article for 7.4 to either version doesn't help either, maybe I'm just looking in the wrong place.

Comment: What appears in the PHP error log?  That should tell you where the immediate problems lie

Comment: Turn on error_reporting and PHP should tell you which functions/methods are deprecated when you run your page

Comment: Set `log_errors=On` in your php.ini to turn on the error log.

Comment: The first line of your code is invalid syntax.  I suggest you change it to `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: If you merely had _deprecated_ code, you wouldn't get a 500 error. Deprecation notices are only that - notices - which don't cause a fatal error. So what you probably have is some code which either calls functions removed from PHP 8.2, or which isn't compatible in some other way. And the way you find out about that is the same way you deal with any other PHP error...by enabling error reporting (or logging, if it's a live server) and then looking at the error, and then deciding what to do about it.It's unclear why this would be any different to (what is hopefully) your usual debugging procedure

Comment: P.S. You seem to have done this change on a hosting environment on a server. Is this your live application server? Did you not test your code against PHP 8.2 in a local development environment before making the change on the server?? You shouldn't really get to that point without knowing, and fixing, all the problems in advance of making the live change.

Comment: I note that the code you've shared includes preparing `$cardsquery` and then attempting to bind parameters that don't exist in the SQL statement.  That could be because you've simplified the code for this question, or it could indicate a genuine error.

Comment: Anyway if this is an internet-facing server then _do not_ turn on on-screen PHP error reporting. There's probably a PHP error log file already you can look at to see what the issue is. If not, or if you can't find it, ask your hosting company to assist you in locating it.

Comment: P.P.S. Not sure which bit of the docs you've been looking at, but https://www.php.net/releases/8.2/en.php summarises the 8.2 changes. If you're upgrading straight from 7.4 you'll also want to look at the changes for all the releases in between as well. There are other sites [if you look around](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+8.2+what%27s+new) which provide more in-depth info about the various changes, too.

Comment: When I've had to upgrade PHP code and find deprecations (or incompatible/removed code), I used JetBrains PHPStorm. It has a code inspector to help with exactly this scenario. You select which version of PHP you want to upgrade to, and let PHPStorm report the lines of code that need attention. It saved me many hours of debugging and fixing problems one by one. Here's a short article describing how to use this code inspector: https://mehulgohil.com/blog/how-to-find-deprecated-usages-in-phpstorm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any hosting service worth using will have somewhere you can access the PHP error logs. If you've got a fatal error in your code, there will *always* be something in those logs, so go straight there. (I'm sure people will suggest exceptions to that rule, but it's true often enough to be worth assuming.)

If you had done that, you would have found that there is a syntax error on the very first line, where you've tried to change a setting:

```
error_reporting(?int $error_level = null): int
```

What you've copied there isn't an example of how to *use* the function, it's a *description* of the function.

What you were probably trying to do was this:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

What that will do is add messages for *non-fatal* problems to wherever the errors are already being logged or displayed. If what you actually wanted was to *display* the errors - which is only needed if you can't find the log file - you need this line instead (or as well):

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Note that if PHP doesn't even get to those lines, they'll have no effect, which is why it's so important to know where your log file is anyway.

Finally, a clarification:

> How do I find deprecated code...?

It's good to understand that "deprecated" means *planned for removal or change in the future*. Deprecated code is not code that is going to break anything right now, it is code that *you are being given plenty of time to fix*. In PHP's case, any deprecation in an 8.x release means removal / change in version 9.0 *at the earliest*.

If your site is actually failing to load, what you're looking for is things that have *already* been changed or removed. Look for the section in the manual and blog articles marked "non-bacwards compatible changes", and look in your log files for *errors*.

Logging warnings as well may sometimes help you track down *why* an error is happening, but it's important to focus on the right place.

Comment: Yeah I did use error_reporting(E_ALL); originally and it didn't work so I thought maybe it was outdated and just copied the first thing from the php site. But I must've done something wrong originally because it works now.

Looks like it was this line $cardsquery->bind_param("ss", $season, $set);

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: The number of variables must match the number of parameters in the prepared statement

Comment: actually I'm dumb. this was old code that I don't even need. I'm not using the parameters for my sql query so I just got rid of that line and everything works now. I guess PHP 7.4 just didn't care to error out because of it... thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Install phpstan and run it through you code with level 0. It will catch and list all syntax errors.

Install the Package

```
composer require --dev phpstan/phpstan
```

Run

```
vendor/bin/phpstan analyse -l 0 {path/to/your/code}
```

Learn more about phpstan here:
https://phpstan.org/user-guide/getting-started and you can watch a video explaining the usage here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zfAuis9LjIA

I also recommend using an IDE, like PHPStorm to better support PHP syntax.